# Proof Verification: Show that sides AC = AB

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I think I've solved the following problem, but I don't know whether my proof is valid. I would appreciate it if someone could verify it for me. Moreover, I feel as if the solution shouldn't be as convoluted, so a shorter/simpler one is also welcomed. Thanks in advance!

---

In the following figure, assume BY=CZ are altitudes. Show that AC=AB.
[image]

---

> *Proof.* Consider the right triangles $\triangle BCY$ and $\triangle CBZ$. Since they share BC as their hypothenuse, and the arm $BY$ is equal to the  arm $CZ$ (by assumption), then, by the Hypothenuse-Leg postulate, they are congruent.
>
> Notice that $\angle YBC$ and $\angle ZCB$ are corresponding, and let $O$ be the point where $BY$ and $CZ$ meet. Then, by the Pons Asinorum, $\triangle BOC$ is isosceles, and $BO=CO$. Then $YO=BY-BO=CZ-CO=OZ$, so $YO=ZO$.
>
> Now draw line $AO$, and consider right triangles $\triangle OZA$ and $\triangle OYA$. Since they share AO as their hypothenuse, and arm $YO$ is equal to arm $ZO$, then, by the Hypothenuse-Leg postulate, they are congruent. Then, $AZ=AY\implies AZ+BZ=AY+CY\implies AB=AC,$ as desired.

---

Comment: It's OK, but you could make it simpler.  Angles CBZ and BCY are already corresponding angles in the congruent triangles established in the first paragraph.  So you are done with one more sentence...

Comment: @fredgoodman I made a typo. It's angles YBC  and Z**CB**.

Comment: First paragraph is good.  $\angle YCB \cong \angle ZBC$ as they are corresponding angles.  Triangles with equal base angles are isosceles.

Comment: @fredgoodman Ohhhhh... I get what  you mean now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would write $$A=\frac{1}{2}bh_b=\frac{1}{2}ch_c$$ since $$h_c=h_b$$ we get $$b=c$$